# What is "the Debian way" to switch the generic Linux kernel to a linux-hardened kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

Basically all I want to do is switch from my generic kernel to the linux-hardened kernel without affecting anything else. Is this possible? I'm running Linux Mint Cinnamon 64-Bit.

Comment: There was a close vote about your question, I modified it to increase its chance for survival. If it conflicts your intent, click "rollback" in the edit history.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "linux-hardened kernel". You can easily compile a kernel yourself with whatever options you prefer; the "Debian way" is to use `make-kpkg`. The kernel package created this way can then be installed without affecting anything else. If the "linux-hardened kernel" requires support in userspace, then you must also install or change whatever is necessary for this support.